# Read only table in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I'm using mysql database. In that I have table called `tbl_user` I need to change this as read only table to every user. How to change the table as read only ?

Comment: Why do you need a table that cannot be changed or edited by any user? :D

Comment: @Terry Seidler It is a table which contains the login credentials for my application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To grant all user select, use public instead of a complete user list

```
REVOKE ALL ON tbl_user FROM PUBLIC
GRANT SELECT ON tbl_user TO PUBLIC
```

Comment: Remember about `GRANT OPTION`. ALL don't remove `GRANT` privilege.

Answer (score 5):

Besides revoking the permission, another way is to take use of trigger

```
/* triggers */
delimiter //

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS stop_table_insert;
CREATE TRIGGER stop_table_insert
  BEFORE INSERT ON `table`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Database maintainance';
END;//

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS stop_table_update;
CREATE TRIGGER stop_table_update
  BEFORE UPDATE ON `table`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
   SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Database maintainance';
END;//

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS stop_table_delete;
CREATE TRIGGER stop_table_delete
  BEFORE DELETE ON `table`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Database maintainance';
END;//


delimiter ;
```

Comment: This one is fine for me, Thanks Mr Wang ^-^

Answer (score 3):

Use the `REVOKE`command and revoke INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE rights from that table for the user

```
REVOKE
    priv_type [(column_list)]
      [, priv_type [(column_list)]] ...
    ON [object_type] priv_level
    FROM user [, user] ...
```

Refer [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/revoke.html)

Answer (score 3):

You need REVOKE update/modify/GRANT privileges to this table for all users and add SELECT.

```
REVOKE ALL ON readonly_table FROM tbl_user ;
GRANT SELECT ON readonly_table TO tbl_user;
```

If user have grant option on readonly_table execute this:

```
REVOKE GRANT OPTION ON readonly_table FROM tbl_user;
```

Read about [The MySQL Access Privilege System](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privilege-system.html)
and [REVOKE documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/revoke.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
GRANT SELECT ON tbl_user TO user;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON tbl_user TO user;
```