# Making Wordpress Mysql Tables Read-only

Tags: mysql, wordpress, innodb

I've searched around the web for a way to achieve this, and found cant find any solution for wordpress. Most of them had messy code, all of them drawbacks. Some ideas revoke previous privileges for mysql user but cant this for wordpress.

I'm looking for a compact and elegant way of providing a read-only representation of a record based on a some wordpress tables (wp-options and wp-users). Surely there must be some simple way to achieve this, right?

Additional info: I have root access to the server, Tables are Innodb, Mysql version is 5.6.23

Thanks for your time, I would greatly appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: how does this not answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12349640/read-only-table-in-mysql

Comment: Hello, Im giving  "- You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GRANT SELECT ON tbl_user TO PUBLIC' at line 2" error message on phpmyadmin when using that codes. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Hope someone can help me...

Comment: `GRANT SELECT ON dbname.tablename TO 'user'@'host.name' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`

Comment: Hello @RickJames Thank you for your suggestion. I used that code but nothing changed. I dont want to making changes on wp_options table from /wp-admin panel. Any idea?