# How to decide users permission on mysql

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, entity-relationship

We are new in relational database and we want to create program. In our database we have company table, project table, section table and user table. We want to give a permission which are read, write to a user.
But if that user belongs to project table then it has write and read permissions but if that user belongs to section table then it has only read permission. So, Our question is how can we decide user's permissions on mysql.

So far we did,
[image: create tables and attributes]

We have tried to use Grant  but it cannot be using in table and it gives a permission only a spesific person. We want to give all the person which belogs to project (write and read). And all the person which belongs to section(only read).

Answer (score 0):

This answer may be useful, something you did.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12349845/12569575
Also at the same page, there is another solution made by trigger.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37873439/12569575

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am looking it.